# Upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 LTS and the UI animations no longer work

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 20.04, compiz, animations

I just upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 LTS and the UI animations no longer work, on searching other forums most people agree its because CompizConfig is no longer supported.

I've still managed to see other people with the 20.04 version supporting animations and was wondering if i could please get help with that cause it subconsciously affects my workflow.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on GNOME, and i mean the general basic animations like minimizing and maximizing windows

Comment: I'm using xfce  with compiz. Is a lot faster and prettier. So you might install Xubuntu and install compiz afterwards

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i just managed to sort it out right now

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem apparently i just had to reinstall my NVIDIA drivers after the upgrade, i used this website

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux